# How to echo out mysqli aliased columns?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Having issues echoing out the sql columns because I want to output the two 
aliased columns that come out of an sql statement whereby I'm doing calculations on certain rows.

I have tried the below code and also by modifying it by replacing the 0 and 1 with the aliased column names, AmountOwed,  KindsOfProducts which didnt work.

### PHP CODE - where the issue is...

```
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "AmountOwed: " . $row[0]. " - KindsOfProducts: " . $row[1]
        ."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
```

### The Messy SQL statement I'm trying to echo

```
@$username=$_POST['username'];      
$sql=  "SELECT SUM(`price` * `quantity`) AS AmountOwed,
COUNT(*) AS KindsOfProducts FROM tablename
WHERE `orderdate` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
and uname = '$username'";
```

Comment: Can you show your `$sql`?

Comment: use `fetch_row` instead of  `fetch_assoc`

Comment: once `print_r($row)` within while loop, I am sure you will get answer you are looking for.

Comment: fetch_row and print_r doesnt work.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile $sql=  "SELECT SUM(`price` * `quantity`) AS AmountOwed,
COUNT(*) AS KindsOfProducts FROM tablename
WHERE `orderdate` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
and uname = '$username'";

Comment: Did u try to run the query on php my admin?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Works perfectly, when I ran this on phpmyadmin, I get two columns returned and values related to that user  https://imgur.com/a/JK6KcN6

Answer (score 0):

The original method I found on Stack was to echo row[0] etc, replace the 0 with the column alias.

Only reason why this didnt work initially was it had a small typo in there, here's the correct code.

```
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "TEXT: " . $row[COLUMNALIAS]. " - MORETEXT: " . $row[COLUMNALIAS]
."<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
```

Comment: Why are you not trying to use `fetch_row` it will make exactly what you want with faster performance
Row with code will be like this `while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {`
and then you can acces it like `$row[0]`